# Is it grammatically correct to write " Such dark as weighs upon the world every night"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, comparisons

Upon reading the LOTR, I came across heavy usage of 'such as' but in an unfamiliar way. "Such finery as never seen before". I was just wondering if what I wrote sounds correct.

Comment: It’s grammatical. Whether the register fits is another matter.

Comment: Can you elucidate a little more on how it registers to you?

Comment: How it registers to ***me*** is that 999 out of 1000 people would use ***darkness*** rather than ***dark*** in the cited context. (But perhaps that's because only one in a thousand people are really "**poets**" :)

Comment: Thank you for your help and opinion!